# Steps of Kubernetes CNI when using Flannel

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, flannel, cni

I have been setting up Kubernets with kubeadm and I have used Flannel to setup the pod network. The setup basically worked but I have been running into all kinds of problems (and bugs) and now I am trying to gain a better understanding of the different steps involved in network setup process (e.g. CNI and flannel).

From an end-user/admin perspective I simply pass `--pod-network-cidr` with some network argument to `kubeadm` and then later I apply a pod configuration for flannel using `kubectl`. Kubernetes will then start a flannel pod on each of my nodes. Assuming everything worked, flannel should then use the container network interfaces (CNI) of Kubernetes to setup the pod network.

As a result of this process I should get a pod network which includes the following:

1. A `cni0` bridge.
2. A `flannel.x` interface.
3. iptables entries to route between the host and the pod network.

The following files and binaries seem to be involved in the setup:

1. `kubectl` reads a CNI configuration such as `/etc/cni/net.d/10-flannel.conflist` and invokes the CNI plugin described in the config file.
2. Somehow a folder `/var/lib/cni` is being created which seems to contain configuration files for the network setup.
3. A CNI plugin such as `/opt/cni/bin/flannel` is run, I don't yet understand what it does.

What am I missing on this list and how does (2.) fit into these steps. How does `/var/lib/cni` get created and which program is responsible for this?

Answer (score 0):

As I see from code of [CNI:](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni/blob/777324ca6b088145925ffb1008b18dfd84e3c783/libcni/api.go#L32)

```
var  (
   CacheDir  =  "/var/lib/cni"
)
```

this folder used as cache dir for CNI and looks like created by CNI plugin.

[Here](https://github.com/containernetworking/cni) you can find detailed documentation about CNI.

#### What is CNI?

CNI (*Container Network Interface*), a  [Cloud Native Computing Foundation](https://cncf.io/)  project, consists of a specification and libraries for writing plugins to configure network interfaces in Linux containers, along with a number of supported plugins. CNI concerns itself only with network connectivity of containers and removing allocated resources when the container is deleted. Because of this focus, CNI has a wide range of support and the specification is simple to implement.

All projects like Calico, Flannel use CNI as a base. That's why they called CNI-plugins

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/) you can find documentation about how kubernetes interact with CNI.